# Choose an event from a list of events happening with different probabilities

Tags: python, probability

I have the situation that I have a list of events that have individual probabilities of happening when condition X is met, for example [0.1, 0.9, 0.2]. They don't add up to 1. However, when condition X is met, at most one of them can happen. The number of events is variable.
What I mean is that if only event A is in the list, the list is e.g. [0.3]. If B is there also it is for example [0.3, 0.8]. And then the question is, which one of them happens, or none.

code:

```
event_prob_list = [0.3, 0.5, 0.8]
```

The length of the list is variable.
I want a function or distribution which gives me one of the indexes, or None, according to which is selected.

One solution that I came up with is: 1.) Shuffle the list randomly. 2.) For each element in the list, throw a coin; if result < element, return index. 3.) If the end of the list is reached, none of them happens.

However, I don't know if that would be correct probability-wise and if there is not a better function/distribution from which to draw.
(I literally edited this question while it was being closed....)

Comment: When the condition is met do you select the event with the highest probability?

Comment: @yudhiesh It's rather about randomly going through them and then making a probability throw if the event should be triggered or not. I could write that, but I thought maybe there already is function or a distribution that does that.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) is what you are looking for?

Comment: It's weird that the probabilities are "independent of each other" but only one of them can happen. Is there a posibility where condition X is met and none of them happen?

Comment: @RoyCohen Yes, that is possible, too. Maybe I didn't use the right terminology, what I mean is that if only event A is in the list, the list is e.g. [0.3]. If B is there also it is for example [0.3, 0.8]. And then the question is, which one of them happens, or none.

Comment: How does this get an upvote? This question lacks everything you need to answer it...

Comment: @Scotty1- What does it lack, exactly?

Comment: Can you give an example in code ?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian I did, but there is just not much code to begin with. I have a list. Now I am hoping for some numpy function to fulfill the goal I described.

Comment: Choose one from ['none', 0.3, 0.5, 0.8]?where  `none` means none of them. Is this your question?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian Yes.

Comment: @LizzAlice Sample code and data and expected results to start with. And, if possible, what you've tried so far.

Comment: It would help if you gave a more specific [mre]. For example, right now it is not clear what is this "condition X" and what exactly you expect to happen when it is met. Do you mean that for each element you check if it can happen with the specified probability? Why can only one of them happen if they are individual?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```py
import random

probs = [0.1, 0.2]
# get max value and create a list of `none` with length of `max*100`
# for this example we create a list of 20 `none`s
mx = int(max(probs) * 100)
probs_placeholder = ['none'] * mx

# then for each probability, we specify probabilty amount of indices to that prob.
# for example if we have 20 cells, 2 cells for 0.1 and 4 cells for 0.2
# because `4/20=0.2` and `2/20=0.1` 
probs_count = [int(mx*x) for x in probs]
index = 0
for i in range(len(probs)):
    probs_placeholder[index:probs_count[i]] = [probs[i]] * probs_count[i]
    index = probs_count[i]

selected_index = random.choice(range(len(probs_placeholder)))
selected_value = probs_placeholder[selected_index]


if selected_value == 'none':
    print('none selected')
else:
    # its possible to have duplicate probs,  So we should start counting until we reach to selected index. 
    acc = 0
    i = -1
    while acc < selected_index and i < len(probs):
        i += 1
        acc += probs_count[i]
    print(i)
```

Comment: Where are the probabilities here? You simply choose randomly between the elements. You might want to use [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with some `weights` but personally I still don't understand from the question how...

Comment: Changing the values to numbers doesn't change the fact that you simply choose one of them randomly, probably with a uniform distribution... According to the OP the numbers should indicate some probability of something to happen, it's just not clear what...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Its closed, my idea was to extend list from `[0.1, 0.3, 0.5]` to `[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]` then we can choose randomly and get index of selected one from initial list.

Comment: Again, you're missing the point that the numbers represent probability. For example, the second element has an 80% chance of being selected. Simply using `choice` doesn't reflect that...

Comment: Yes, you're right.Its complicated than it looks.@Tomerikoo
But i think atleast it can  give a point to start.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I updated my answer, Please check it from your sight.